# Create aliases in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, alias

I want to create a permanent alias in PowerShell for all executables located within Cygwin's `bin` directory:

```
C:\Cygwin64\bin
```

I can do it for individual executable like `grep` via:

```
Set-Alias grep  "C:\cygwin64\bin\grep"
```

When I try to create an alias for the `bin` directory, it does not work:

```
Set-Alias Cygwin C:\cygwin64\bin\

  Cygwin\grep ... it failed with this error:

  Cygwin\grep : The module 'cygwin' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Cygwin'.

  At line:1 char:1
  + Cygwin\grep
  + ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cygwin\grep:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

How can I create an alias to the `bin` directory so I can call any executable from it?

Comment: Simply add the folder to `$PATH`: `Cmd /c Setx /M Path "%PATH%;C:\Cygwin64\bin;"` then close and re-open a terminal to reload `$PATH`. You can also do so via a PowerShell command _(the command above will work in PowerShell)_, but like everything with PowerShell, it's vastly more complex than it realistically should be - please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29109007/6819406) answer.

Comment: I tried to run but it failed:
> $PATH; Cmd /c Setx /M Path "%PATH%;C:\Cygwin64\bin;"
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.

Comment: I'm unsure why that's erroring out with that - execute `cmd` from within PowerShell, then run the command, and it'll execute successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Set-Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-create-an-alias-to-an-executable-file) is for function, script or files, not folders.
Use the `-Name` and `-Value` properties to described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-create-an-alias-to-an-executable-file):

> The Set-Alias cmdlet creates an alias in the current PowerShell session. The Name parameter specifies the alias's name, np. The Value parameter specifies the path and application name C:\Windows\notepad.exe.

In you case, the cmdlet will be:

```
Set-Alias -Name grep -Value 'C:\cygwin64\bin\grep.exe'
```

You can use [New-PSDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.3) as shown on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597839/create-a-folder-alias-in-powershell) from StackOverflow to turn your folder into a new powershell drive.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill For me it does answer the question as the OP wants to use Set-Alias for something it is not build for. He/She won't be able to use Set-Alias directly.

Comment: Thanks Folks, I used New-PSDrive  option